# Explain Ajax code order

Tags: ajax

I use Ajax a lot for my web projects but just now I want to fully understand it. I got into this problem.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;//get response
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();//send request
}
```

Look at the code. In my logic I think we have to send request first then get response later.
So why in ajax code we get response before send request.
Am I missing something here?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;//get response
    }
  };
```

is defining a callback function (asynchronous). This function is only called when your `xmlhttprequest` object changes state (you attached it to the `onreadystatechange` event). You need to define the callback function before you make the call itself (`xhttp.open`) otherwise it won't know what to do, but the code itself does not run until the state of the `xmlrequestobject` changes.